# Determine the size of a UITableView on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have got to devide the width of a table into 2, 3, 5, ... equal parts. The purpose is to fill a table cell with 2, 3, 5, ... equally sized square subviews. (Images)
Naturally, the height of the table depends on that.

This is how I determine the size of the table and devide it by the number of images to be placed. 
The method numberOfPicsPerRow returns that integer value of the number of images that the user has chosen to be displayed in each row of the table.

```
- (CGFloat) rowHeight{

    fcAppAppDelegate *delegate = (fcAppAppDelegate *);

    CGRect      bounds = self.tableView.bounds;
    //CGRect          bounds = self.view.bounds; // Alternative that returns the same result.
    float       tableWidth; 
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].tabBarController.interfaceOrientation))
        tableWidth = bounds.size.width;
    else
        tableWidth = bounds.size.height;

    NSLog (@"tableWidth: %f", tableWidth);
    return tableWidth / [MatrixPhotoListTVC noOfPicsPerRow];
}
```

This is where I set the table's row height for the first time:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.rowHeight = [self rowHeight];

}
```

All works fine on an iPhone. On an iPad however, the tableView.bounds or view.bounds returns (width=320, heiht=372).
Interestingly the the values are correct when the device is rotated. (width=768, height=960)

Does anybody have an explanation for that? Is viewDidLoad not an appropriate place to determin the Table's size?

Answer (score 1):

Someteimes speaking about it - in this case writing the question - makes all the difference.

However, it may happen to others as well and therefore I keep the question in the system. This is the answer:

viewDidLoad is called immediatley after the view was loded. This means in most cases it was loaded from a Nib file. The nib file I was using is sesigned for iPhone only and not for iPad dimensions. 
That is why the views dimensions are exactly what they were in IB.

I moved the call from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear and there it works fine. Apparently iOS automatically resizses the view for iPad (which it does nicely) between the calls of viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear.

If anyone knows a better place from an academic or documentational point of view where I could place the call, then a hint is highly appreciated.

However, now it seems to work fine.

Comment: You're doing it right. In `viewDidLoad:` the view was just loaded, it's the same as you created in IB, including the size. Then, before the view is added to the view hierarchy, it is being resized according to the autoresizing mask, then `viewWillAppear:` is called and then the view is added. That's why in `viewDidLoad:` the dimensions *should* be correct for the current view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I would switch your code to the methods -viewWillAppear or -viewDidAppear as any layout has already been done by the table view.

Another possibility if UITableView is subclassed is subclassing the method:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Isn't that a bit too late? I am going to set the tableView's row hight because the standard value does not fit.

Comment: You are correct that - (void)viewDidLoad is a better place for it. My code has a custom UITableView and cells that need laying out when the table view is reloaded hence why I use the above method instead. But that only makes sense if you have already subclassed UITableView. Managing everything from the controller is the way it should be if possible. Amended my answer to leave it a possibility and not a more appropriate options than the first solutions given.